# Java 1.7 still telling me that strings in switch statements are incompatible

Tags: java, string, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, switch-statement

I'm using java 1.7 in intellij and it's giving me a compile error as if I'm using pre-1.7.  Saying, "Incompatible type. Found 'java.lang.String'. required 'byte, char, short, or int'.

I'm rattling my brain trying to figure out why this is.  Thanks

Comment: Please post the code!!!

Comment: @shekharsuman Actually it's clear, that's a problem with compiler settings in IDE.

Comment: I doubt that unless clarified by OP! @MarounMaroun...

Comment: I just did a test in IntelliJ. If I have the project language level set to 6, I see the problem you have. If I change it to 7, the "problem" goes away.

Comment: @shekharsuman why do you doubt that? Its most probaly the reason. he installed java 1,7, but the project has setted compiler version to 1.6 or prior

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to change language level in your IDE.

Check these settings:

- File > Project Structure > Project > Project SDK
- File > Project Structure > Project > Project Language Level
- File > Project Structure > Modules > Your module > Sources > Language Level
- File > Project Structure > Modules > Your module > Dependencies > Module SDK

Also check compiler settings. Sometimes it adds extra arguments to compiler:

- File > Settings > Compiler > Java Compiler > Byte code version

If you use maven plugin enable auto-import. Then the language level will be detected automatically from your `pom.xml` settings.

Comment: This is really helped me in intellij 2021.2.3

Answer (score 1):

In your project settings most probably you use java compiler java 1.6 or prior.
Change that to java 1.7

Answer (score 0):

I think you have installed multiple JDKs on your system or you are using the default JDK that is bundled with IDE intellij. Try [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23455956-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under) link to change your JDK path to the one that is 1.7 or higher if any installed on your system 
or update your JDK to the latest version available

Answer (score 0):

I solved my case like this:

Intellij

File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Project language level:

And in the options box I selected the option:

14 - Switch expressions

Answer (score 0):

If you add this to your `pom.xml` file it will resolve the issue where the key part is the `source 1.8`:

```
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```